# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error in Azure Functions when running Python Code

Tags: python-2.7, azure-functions, serverless

I am new to Azure but I have been working on AWS Lambda for quite a time now. I want to make the same lambda function which is written in py 2.7 to work on azure functions. When I created new function there was no python option thus I created with javascipt and created a new file. I deleted the JS File and now am trying to run the Python File. But it is always showing me an error

[image: Error shown everytime]

[image: Full Code with Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Function is Available with python support
Just Click on "Create your own function" instead of templates above the create link. 
[image]

You can use that for the same.
Here is my working example.
[image]

Comment: I wan to work with Blob Trigger in python , I have made the same in S3 with Lambda. Is it possible to make the same with Python in Azure Functions and Azure Storage?

Comment: Yes It is possible although it not available on MS official documentation but still you can do this https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/blob-trigger-blob-in-out-bindings

Comment: Which **template** to use for making it.? Because python only supports 2 template HTTP Trigger and Queue Trigger. @Tushar

Comment: You should create another question to explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! If you require faster or more reliable blob processing, consider creating a queue trigger.